# parse specific data in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, mgrammar

I have data stored in specific text format:

```
FIDS_A1=CF_LAST:1|line_NETCHNG:2|QoS:3; FIDS_A2=[High and Low]:[{High} – {Low}]:1|CF_LAST:2; FIDS_A3=YR_RANGE:3|VOL:3; FIDS_A4=GR_AskBid; FIDS_C3=line_BID:3|line_ASK:3;
```

I need to parse it and get a C# typed data structure from it.

It's not simple to write parser in C# (very many Regexps and hard code).

I heard something about Oslo\MGrammar from Microsoft. Does this tool generate C# parser code for my specific data ?

Output i need only C# code of parser without reference to other libraries.

Comment: Depends greatly on how the text data looks like... Mind to share?

Comment: Actually it’s very simple to write a parser in C#, it just is a lot of work. Parser generators help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parser generators don't help you avoid regexes. In fact, at least for the generators I used, a parser generator is a *second* stage of parsing. It accepts a stream of tokens, and outputs an abstract syntax tree.

In order to convert text to tokens, you would write a lexer, and that can include a regex or three.

If the language is simple enough, you might find it less work to write a parser from scratch than to learn how to use a parser generator.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the [GOLD Parser Builder](http://www.devincook.com/) and the [bsn GoldParser engine](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-goldparser/) (which can create a typed data structure when parsing the data using a grammar built with GOLD).

There's also a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/bsn_interpreter.aspx) which shows how to use this engine.

Comment: It's good solution but result parser will contain bsn.GoldParser reference. But i need only C# source code without depending on other libs

Comment: You can always use ILMERGE to merge the external lib into your project, so that there is no (visible) external reference.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modelcitizen/archive/2010/09/22/update-on-sql-server-modeling-ctp-repository-modeling-services-quot-quadrant-quot-and-quot-m-quot.aspx) on `M`'s status I don't see it coming to the market very soon.

I suggest using [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/), which:

- is able to generate very powerful parsers in C# among others.
- is a very mature product - has it's own IDE with debugger
- uses standard EBNF grammars, so you won't invest your time in something that will die out soon